# Is this thread-safe in Java?

Tags: java, static, thread-safety

Is the following static method "contains" safe from a visibility perspective?

```
    public class MyTest {
      private static final HashSet<String> mySet= new HashSet<String>();

      static {
        mySet.add("cat");
        mySet.add("dog");
        mySet.add("bird");
      }

      public static boolean contains(String key) {
        return mySet.contains(key);
      }
    }
```

So then if multiple threads call MyTest.contains(string) are they guaranteed to see the correct contents of mySet?

My thought is yes, because it is a final reference in which all the data is added to the set in the static block (and does not later change).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is thread safe. `static` initializer blocks are run when the class is initialized and [that is done behind a lock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2). So `mySet` is initialized fully before it is published (made available). All threads will see it fully constructed.

Comment: Note that it's still possible (though the code here doesn't do it) for methods to make changes to the set, after it's been initialized.  That won't be thread-safe unless all access to the set are synchronized.  If the set's contents aren't meant to change, consider using [`Collections.unmodifiableSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableSet-java.util.Set-) to protect against accidental changes.

Comment: @bayou.io - If there is no `final` here and 'mySet' is changed, will that not mean a call to `contains` is no longer threadsafe?

Comment: @Ross - sure. the assumption is that all writes were done in the static initializer.